# WP8 - prevent "Copy to Clipboard" icon from appearing over selected text

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8

Is there any way to prevent the "Copy to Clipboard" icon from appearing over selected text in a Windows Phone 8 xaml/c# application?

In my application, I'm programmatically setting a TextBox's SelectionStart and SelectionLength properties in the TextBox's TextChanged event to create an Intellisense effect. The code is working well overall, but the "Copy to Clipboard" icon that always appears below the selected text gets really annoying, especially since the user would never want to actually copy this text.

I've spent several hours looking for a solution and would greatly appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you are using built in keypad, with a TextBox, it is
>   not possible to disable the 'copy to clipboard' option.

More details you can find [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/06644b74-1d27-4d20-b2a2-60979b9b4d9e/how-to-disable-copypaste-in-textbox-in-windows-phone-using-c?forum=wpdevelop)

Comment: Alright, I had suspected such but wasn't certain... thanks for the clarification!